# Calendar module translation

Tags: 7, views, datetime

I have installed the [Calendar](https://www.drupal.org/project/calendar) module and would like to translate a few fields:

[image]

At the above screenshot, I'm looking for the day strings ("Sun", "Mon", "Tue", Wed",...). I've been searching everywhere, but can't find where they are located.

Where can I find these strings so I can translate them in the language I prefer?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Administration > Configuration > Regional and language > Translate interface` and search for `!day-abbreviation`. Then translate these strings to the language you prefer.